# Steps to Making a Customized Wordpress Website

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to hire a freelance programmer and designer to customize my Wordpress site, but I am not sure what I should do first.  (Sorry, extreme newbie here)

Should I hire a designer to design the website down to the pixel, and then give those images to the programmer?

Or can I hire the programmer first, make a working beta site, and then hire a designer to fix it up.

Which one would be the most efficient?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, you can find someone from any of these three categories: designer, developer, or designer **and** developer.  Stack Overflow isn't necessarily the question to be asking these questions, but since you're new here, I'll try to point you in a good direction.

I personally would suggest hiring one freelancer to do both and that's because when they go to program the website, they know their design's intentions.  I'll tell you as a programmer, there's nothing more frustrating than being given a website design with absolutely no context to it.  Just being told to "take what you see and make it into code" isn't generally enough direction for a developer to go on.

Here's a few websites I'd look at for someone to help you out further:

- http://www.wordpressfreelance.com/
- http://www.freelancer.com/hire/Wordpress
- https://www.elance.com <- I've heard particularly good things about this site.